Relationship between drift velocity and processor speed
Does having higher drift velocity for electrons lead to faster processors? If yes, how? The speed of processors is higher or lower depending on the speed of the on off states, i.e. the speed of the clock it can support. How does drift velocity fit into this?
Context: a recently developed graphene semiconductor at Georgia institute of tech promises to speed up processors, possibly bringing them into the realm of Terahertz. That's an astounding 1000x increase in performance. How does low resistance lead to faster switching in electronics?

The connections between component have electrical capacitance. To switch from 0 to 1 these capacitances have to be charged to a certain voltage, and they have to be discharged again when switching from 1 to 0 occurs. This takes some time, and before it is finished the rest of the circuit will not see that the switching in one of the gates has taken place.
Now as you already suggest, higher drift velocity gives the switches lower resistance, and if the switching devices have lower resistance, the charging and discharging of capacitances will go faster. And maybe not just the switches, but also the connecting structures can get lower resistance. If this really can make things 1000 times faster, as claimed, remains of course to be seen (admittedly the claim was "possibly" bringing them into the realm of Terahertz, and there is always a possibility!)
To be complete, it is also possible to speed things up by reducing the capacitance. That is (indirectly) related to the drift velocity, because if the material has lower resistance to begin with, then the connections can be made thinner without getting too much resistance, and thinner lines have less capacitance. Other miniaturizations might help as well, if graphene developments make them possible, but that's a bit outside the scope of the question asked here.
